# Compare original array with a secondary array and change value if matched with original array

Tags: arrays, swift, higher-order-functions

I have an original array with "tags" (40 rows) with an objects with:

```
tag: String?
selected: Bool? (false)
```

I then make a new array with "tags" from the original array lets say with 5 rows. Where selected is true.

I now want to change selected = true in my original array with the matching tags.

This was my bet:

```
originalArray = originalArray.filter{ selectedTags.map({ $0.tag }).contains($0.tag) }.forEach({ $0.selected = true})

Cannot invoke 'forEach' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (TagViewModel) throws -> ())'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
yourOriginalArray.forEach({
    let tempItem = $0
    if yourSelectedArray.contains( { return $0.tag == tempItem.tag } ) {
        $0.selected = true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Breek's answer better and he posted while I was still typing my answer up, but here it is anyway! You can do something like:

```
struct TagViewModel : Equatable {
    var tag: String
    var selected: Bool

    init(tag: String, selected: Bool) {
        self.tag = tag
        self.selected = selected
    }
}

func ==(lhs: TagViewModel, rhs: TagViewModel) -> Bool {
    return lhs.tag == rhs.tag
}

var originalArray = [
    TagViewModel(tag: "1", selected: false),
    TagViewModel(tag: "2", selected: false),
    TagViewModel(tag: "3", selected: false),
    TagViewModel(tag: "4", selected: false),
    TagViewModel(tag: "5", selected: false),
    TagViewModel(tag: "6", selected: true),
    TagViewModel(tag: "7", selected: false),
    TagViewModel(tag: "8", selected: true),
    TagViewModel(tag: "9", selected: false)
]

let newArray = [
    TagViewModel(tag: "1", selected: true),
    TagViewModel(tag: "2", selected: true),
    TagViewModel(tag: "3", selected: true)
]

for tagViewModel in newArray {
    if let index = originalArray.indexOf(tagViewModel) {
        originalArray[index].selected = tagViewModel.selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do something like:

```
originalArray = originalArray.map({ element in
    let newArrayFiltered = newArray.filter({ $0.tag == element.tag })
    return (newArrayFiltered.count > 0) ? (newArrayFiltered[0]) : (element)
})
```

Although I like @breek's response :)